# Pygame: Character Centered Movement System (Diablo II like click-to-move)

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am currently working on a new RPG game using Pygame (my aim here is really to learn how to use object oriented programming). I started a few days ago and developed a movement system where the player clicks a location and the character sprite goes to that location and stops when it get's there by checking if the sprite 'collides' with the mouse position.

I quickly found however that this greatly limited the world size (to the app window size).

I started having a look into making a movement system where the background would move with respect to the player, hence providing the illusion of movement.

I managed to achieve this by creating a variable keeping track of my background map position. The map is much bigger than the app window. And each time I want my player to move I offset the background by the speed of the player in the opposite direction.

My next problem now is that I can't get my character to stop moving... because the character sprite never actually reaches the last position clicked by the mouse, since it is the background that is moving, not the character sprite.

I was thinking of spending some time coding in a variable that would keep track of how many displacements it would take the character sprite to reach the mouse clicked position if it was to move. Since the background moves at the character sprite's speed it would take as many displacement of the background in the x and y directions to center the clicked position on the background to the character sprite at the center of the screen.

It would be something like that:

```
If MOUSEBUTTON clicked:
   NM = set number of moves needed to reach the clicked position based on character sprite distance to click and character sprite speed.
If NM != 0:
   Move background image
Else:
   pass
```

This would mean that when my background has moved enough for the character sprite to now be just over the area of the background that was originally clicked by the player, the movement would stop since NM == 0.

I guess that my question is: Does that sound like a good idea or will it be a nightmare to handle the movement of other sprites and collisions ? And are there better tools in Pygame to achieve this movement system ?

I could also maybe use a clock and work out how many seconds the movements would take.

I guess that ultimately the whole challenge is dealing with a fixed reference point and make everything move around it, both with respect to this fixed reference, but also to their own. e.g. If two other sprites move toward one another, and the character of the player also "moves" then the movement of the other two sprites will have to depend both on the position of the other sprite and also on the offset of the background caused by the movement of the player's character.

An interesting topic which has been frying my brain for a few nights !

Thank you for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually asking for an opinion on game design. The way I look at it, nothing is impossible so go ahead and try your coding. Also it would be wise to look around at similar projects scattered around the net. You may be able to pick up a lot of tips without re inventing the wheel. Here is a good place to start.

[scrolling mini map](http://thepythongamebook.com/en:pygame:step022)

Comment: Thank you for the link I will have a look at it. As I said, I am new to Pygame and I didn't want to spend a lot of time re-inventing the wheel. Especially since I would assume this movement system to be broadly used. Having said that it looks like most games use arrow keys or WASD rather than mouse click.